# Get current user who is using sudo

Tags: shell-script, sudo

So, let's say I have a shell script that's supposed to be run as root, but I want to execute commands using runuser as the user who is running sudo. I could do `runuser -u tux echo penguin`. However, what if I want to get the username of the user that ran `sudo` from within the root shell as root, to avoid hard-coding the username to run as into the script. How can I do this?

Comment: If you want to find who started some running application (using `sudo`), I would use a command line with `ps`: `ps -ef |grep 'sudo '` and look at the user name in the first column.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `SUDO_USER` variable:

```shellsession
$ env | grep SUDO
$ sudo env | grep SUDO
SUDO_COMMAND=/sbin/env
SUDO_USER=terdon
SUDO_UID=1000
SUDO_GID=1000
```

So, you can just check if the `$SUDO_USER` variable is set or not:

```bash
if [ -n "$SUDO_USER" ]
then
   # run commands related to the original invoking user
fi
```